# How delete/anonymize sensitive data and keep its integrity?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, paper-trail-gem

I am working on [Calcometer](https://github.com/a160v/calcometer), an app that helps healthcare workers (and sales people) keep track of the distance and time they spend driving between appointments.

Tech stack: Ruby on Rails, StimulusJS and Bootstrap.

## Goal

Be GDPR compliant about patient data deletion while not breaking main app logic

---

### Description

**Models (5)**: address, appointment, patient, trip, user.
**Schema**

```
create_table "addresses", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "street"
    t.string "number"
    t.string "zip_code"
    t.string "city"
    t.string "state"
    t.string "country"
    t.float "latitude"
    t.float "longitude"
    [...]
  end

  create_table "appointments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.datetime "start_time"
    t.datetime "end_time"
    t.bigint "user_id"
    t.bigint "patient_id"
    [...]
  end

  create_table "patients", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.bigint "client_id", null: false
    t.bigint "address_id", null: false
    [...]
  end

  create_table "trips", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.bigint "start_appointment_id", null: false
    t.bigint "end_appointment_id", null: false
    t.float "driving_distance"
    t.integer "driving_time"
    [...]
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "name"
    t.string "last_name"
    [...]
  end
```

### User flow

1. User creates a patient and inputs their address.
2. User creates n appointments for all patients they met during the current_day.
3. App calculates a trip based on a start_appointment and an end_appointment (whenever >2 appointments exist in the current_day)
   3a. in the trip model, start_appointment and end_appointment are validated to avoid overlapping.
   3b. in the appointment model, start_time and end_time are validated (and latter must be after the first).
4. A recalculate_trip service is triggered every day at 1am to recalculate trips of previous day for data integrity purposes.
   4a. Deleting an appointment will trigger the service for the same day
5. [WIP] User can export (email) trips data for a given time range for their client/employer.

### Main methods

Method to calculate driving distance using Geocoder

```ruby
def calculate_driving_distance
   coordinates1 = start_appointment.patient.address.latitude, start_appointment.patient.address.longitude
   coordinates2 = end_appointment.patient.address.latitude, end_appointment.patient.address.longitude
   Geocoder::Calculations.distance_between(coordinates1, coordinates2) if coordinates1 && coordinates2
end
```

Method to calculate driving time based on driving_distance and average speed in Switzerland (50 km/h)

```ruby
def calculate_driving_time
   (calculate_driving_distance.to_f / AVERAGE_SPEED \* 60).round if calculate_driving_distance  
end
```

---

### Issues

#### #1 Data integrity when deleting Patient account

Patient data is name, last_name and address_id; as this is sensitive data, I want to make sure the app is GDPR compliant, therefore whenever a user wants to delete patient data, it is deleted/anonymised.

#### #2 Updating method calculate_driving_distance

Currently, whenever a patient is deleted, this will cause issues in the distance_calculation method as coordinates are fetched from the patient through the appointment (coordinates1 = start_appointment.patient.address.latitude); so when a patient is deleted, the patient becomes nil and no more coordinates

I already checked [this (old) answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22167393/keep-historical-database-relations-integrity-when-data-changes), however it seems outdates (9+ yo) and I would like to know more recent best practices for database design.

For issue 1, I thought about these two mutually exclusive options:

*Proposed solution A*:  implement a soft delete solution with [paper_trail](https://github.com/paper-trail-gem/paper_trail) gem

*Proposed solution B*: permanently delete patient data.

For issue 2, I also thought about the following two options:

*Proposed solution C*: implement soft delete and never have this issue

*Proposed solution D*:  whenever an appointment is created, set address_id = patient.address_id; and updated coordinates fetching

from

`coordinates1 = start_appointment.patient.address.latitude`

to

`coordinates1 = start_appointment.address.latitude`

Thanks for reading so far, I am happy to read your proposed solutions and feedback.

Comment: “Best practice” Is opinionated. Am address ID isn’t sensitive data, the address is. Once a patient is “deleted” do you still need to calculate distances? If so, you either need to not delete the address (likely not compliant but I don’t recall), or calculate distance at the time the appointment is made and store in the appointment (seems best) because distance isn’t sensitive, and appointments don’t need to be deleted.

Comment: Same problem occurs if a patient relocates and the address is updated. You should decouple the data needed to track appointments from the patient's current address data.

Comment: @DaveNewton: I don't need to calculate distances once a patient is 'deleted' as the calculation should be done previously. However, the distance is stored in the trip, appointments are used only as starting and ending addresses for the Trip.

Comment: Then what's the specific issue? If the distance is stored on the trip, why would you ever need to recalculate it once the patient's data is soft-deleted/anonymized? If you have fkey refs then a hard-delete isn't really an option *(it rarely is with a data model of any complexity, really)*, a flag + anonymizing handles that issue and is GDPR-compliant *(to the best of my knowledge)*.